# mariadb connection string to r

Tags: azure, mariadb

I am trying to use a VM machine with R on Azure. I want to connect it to a mariaDB on Azure.

I use the RmySQL package, and I use the following connection string:

```
require(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
             dbname="energidb",
            host="energidb.mariadb.database.azure.com",
            port=3306,
            user="USER",
            password="MY_PWD")
```

However, No luck I have in trying this, as R says. "Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'energidb'"

On azure, I promise and guarentee with my life, the name of the mariaDB is "energidb"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the database?

Comment: yes.. i am staring at the database.. its extremly frustrating...

Comment: ..and its not a firewall issue, i think..i have set that up

Comment: Show us the command you used to create that database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just create a Maria DB resource on Azure portal, then you should only have a database server.

You can connect to the Maria DB without specifying a database name. And then list all the existing databases as following:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
            host="your host address, jackmariadb.mariadb.database.azure.com",
            port=3306,
            user="user name, jack@jackmariadb",
            password="password, d*******5")
rs = dbSendQuery(con, "show databases")
fetch(rs, n=-1)
```

In my case, it will just show the 3 system databases:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that on Azure, I created a mariaDB server (without any database). The database reference i made was to the server, which ofcourse is meaningless.

The solution is first to create a database (which is done by pointing at the server). From there I can point on the database.